# get list of all directories and subdirectories with equal or same size

Tags: bash, shell-script

I can get the size of all directories and their sub-directories using:

```
% /usr/bin/du -b */
4096    dest/src/_adoc
4096    dest/src/_txt
12288   dest/src
28117   dest/
4096    src/_adoc
4096    src/_txt
12818   src/
```

How I search all directories and sub-directories to find directories with similar size? For example, in this case the following has similar size.

```
4096    dest/src/_adoc
4096    dest/src/_txt
4096    src/_adoc
4096    src/_txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU tools, you could do:

```
du -b | expand -t12 | sort | uniq -Dw12
```

That assumes that directory names don't contain newline characters, that directory cumulative sizes don't exceed 999999999999 bytes. That also expands tabs (including the ones occurring in file names).

To remove those limitations, you could make it instead (still with GNU tools):

```
du -b0 | sort -zn | awk -v RS='\0' -F'\t' '
  {
    if ($1 == prev) {
      if (!n++) print prev_line
      print
    } else {
      n = 0
      prev = $1
      prev_line = $0
    }
  }'
```